# Split text with split function

Tags: python, split

Im trying to split in python 3.6.

What I need is only **abc-1.4.0.0**

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
#print(mytext)
mytext = str.split("_bla.blub = '");
#print (mytext)
print (mytext[1].split("'")[0])
```

but my result is empty. Why?

Comment: I think Sama is trying to split `mytext` on the string `"_bla.blub = '"` so that it returns a 1 element list with `'abc-1.4.0.0';` in it, but there are several errors that I'm trying to decipher...

Comment: `mytext[13:24]` unless you need to split it fancy because things are changing.

Comment: If you uncommenting those `print()`s I think you'd see what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
mytext = str.split(mytext);
mytext

['_bla.blub', '=', "'abc-1.4.0.0';"]

mytext[2]
"'abc-1.4.0.0';"
```

OR

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"

mytext = mytext.split("_bla.blub = '")

print (mytext[1].split("'")[0])
abc-1.4.0.0
```

OR

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
mytext = mytext.split("'");
mytext

['_bla.blub', '=', "'abc-1.4.0.0';"]

mytext[1]
'abc-1.4.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually acting on `mytext`.

Try the following:

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
#print(mytext)
mytext = mytext.split("_bla.blub = '")
#print (mytext)
print (mytext[1].split("'")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
print(mytext)
mytext = mytext.split("'");
print (mytext)
print (mytext[0])
print (mytext[1])
```

You need to call `.split()` on your string and save it into a variable instead of calling `.split()` on the `str`class. [Try this.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7eyJLWiRMFWQSk@KSdRLymnNAnIUU9MStY11DPRM9AzULdW4iooyswr0YCo1eSC64Ew9IoLcjJLNJTUlTStISoV4EpRuNEGsegihrGa//8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simpler method (split by single quote):

```
mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
print(mytext.split("'")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module for such string related stuff. Below is *the sample code to extract all the substrings between the single quotes from the given string*:

```
>>> import re

>>> mytext = "_bla.blub = 'abc-1.4.0.0';"
>>> re.findall("'([^']*)'", mytext)
['abc-1.4.0.0']
```